# Smarter way to load config values in python?

Tags: python

Currently I load values like so (using configparser)

```
my_value = config.get("my", "value")
```

But I find myself loading alot of values sometimes as my program grows over time. Is there any "prettier"/better way to load all values in a config file?

Was perhaps thinking of json but not really sure? One problem with json is its not very easy for newbies to understand, and I cant comment the sections in json?

Comment: I like python settings module and also yaml should be considered as an option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use ConfigParser, you can store your config values in a dictionary indexed by `[section name][item name]`, and load them without having to explicitly specify each variable name:

```
import ConfigParser
from pprint import pprint
cfg = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
cfg.read('config.cfg')
CONFIG_DATA = {}
for section_name in cfg.sections():
    CONFIG_DATA[section_name] = {}
    for item_name in cfg.items(section_name):
        CONFIG_DATA[section_name][item_name] = cfg.get(section_name, item_name)
pprint(CONFIG_DATA)
```

Comment: Thanks! This is pretty much what I wanted to do :-)

Comment: Perhaps you could help me once again, I'm getting an error msg (see here: http://pastebin.com/ULuzUwYz ) when running the code. The config file im loading is https://github.com/jkaberg/uProcess/blob/master/config.cfg

Cant really seem to figure why it would complain about tuples?

Comment: Hi Joel, no problem, post it as a question I can have a look.

Comment: Posted a new issue here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17061852/getting-tuple-error-when-trying-to-parse-config-file Thanks for your help :-)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to save the configuration as a Python dict in a YAML file. YAML is human-readable and supports comments with a # sign at the beginning of a line. However, it does not support block comments.

```
import yaml
conf = {"name":"john", "password":"asdf"}
with open("conf.yaml", "w") as f:
    yaml.dump(conf, f)
```

will give you a file conf.yaml with the content:

```
{name: john, password: asdf}
```

You can then read this with:

```
import yaml
with open("conf.yaml", "r") as f:
    conf = yaml.load(f)
```

You might consider using XML if you need block comments.

Comment: The configparser module also supports comments using `#` or `;`: http://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html

Answer (score 0):

What about simply using Python modules?

You can just have a config.py file including something like the following:

```
# config.py
MY = "value"
DB = "mysql://..."

LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': True,
    'formatters': {
    },
    'handlers': {
    },
    'loggers': {
    }
}
```

And then import that file when you need it:

```
import config
import logging.config

logging.config.dictConfig(config.LOGGING)
print config.MY
```

Answer (score -1):

In a Java application I developed I had hundreds of parameters in a static class called Resources that I needed to make configurable by the user via a XML file without breaking the existing application.

What I did was to use introspection to read the name and type of each property of the Resources class and then search the XML file for an element with the same name and assign the value, if found, to that property.

It should be easier in Python since it's a dynamic language so you don't need to bother with type safety and casting (which is not necessarily a good thing...)

Comment: This question asks about Python not Java. It would have been more helpful to provide a code sample for how to load XML config in Python.