# Getting tuple error when trying to parse config file

Tags: python

I recived a good snipet on howto parse an config file into a dictionary earlyer, but I can't seem to find why it can't parse my config file (since I dont have any tuples outside the comments)

My error msg,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "test2.py", line 9, in
<module>
    CONFIG_DATA[section_name][item_name] = cfg.get(section_name, item_name)   File "C:\Python27\lib\ConfigParser.py", line 614, in get
    option = self.optionxform(option)   File "C:\Python27\lib\ConfigParser.py", line 374, in optionxform
    return optionstr.lower() AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

The code,

```
import ConfigParser
from pprint import pprint
cfg = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
cfg.read('config2.cfg')
CONFIG_DATA = {}
for section_name in cfg.sections():
    CONFIG_DATA[section_name] = {}
    for item_name in cfg.items(section_name):
        CONFIG_DATA[section_name][item_name] = cfg.get(section_name, item_name)
pprint(CONFIG_DATA)
```

My config file, 
http://pastebin.com/UKnrXFGR

Comment: But why are you doing it in the first place? `ConfigParser` is meant to parse and store you data, so you'll be able to retrive it whe nyou need. What it the resons for copying everythin from it to a dictionary?

Comment: This is mainly for learning purposes actully :)

Answer (score 2):

> `ConfigParser.items(section[, raw[, vars]])`
>
> Return a list of `(name, value)` pairs for each option in the given section. Optional arguments have the same meaning as for the `get()` method.

Either do:

```
for item_name in cfg.options(section_name): # Note `options`
    CONFIG_DATA[section_name][item_name] = cfg.get(section_name, item_name)
```

or:

```
for item_name, item_value in cfg.items(section_name):
    CONFIG_DATA[section_name][item_name] = item_value
```

Comment: Nice, didnt see that! Is it possible for it to process booleans and ints aswell? Currently I use cfg.getboolean() or cfg.getint()

As you can see in config I've got some booleans and ints

Comment: @JoelKåberg ahm… I'm afraid I didn't get your question… If you want to use convenience methods like `getint` then you definitely shouldn't be copying all the data from the config object to your dictionary.